# Boost in an MFC app on NT4

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, mfc, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to modify a current MFC application running on Windows NT4 to use boost libraries for ethernet communcications (originally, it used CommX for serial) and general increased performance, effieciency, and clarity of code.

I started out modifying it in VS2010, but I found that I was unable to produce a valid NT4 app with VS2010. I googled the issue and found that VS2005 was the last version able to create an NT4 app. I got everything to compile in VS2005, but found that I had to change certain #define statements in stdafx.h in order to get the app to run on NT4. However, even after doing that, when I execute the program on NT4, it immediately quits with no error. It doesn't show anything. I even checked the Task Manager processes while executing it. It is like it never executed at all.

I got desperate and tried compiling the app in VS2003, but I got so many errors that I gave that up.

My last attempt was VC6, but again, I got 262 errors and started wondering whether it was even possible for boost to run in VB6 or on an NT4 machine.

Is it even possible to compile and run an MFC app with boost libraries on an NT4 machine? If so, which environment/compiler do I need and how do I configure it to work correctly?

This is a very tight-schedule project, so any (prompt) help would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Did you run under the debugger?  That should tell you where the program quits, even if you have to single step.

Comment: You said "for boost to run in VB6".. Did you mean "for boost to run in VC6"?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use VC6 to compile code that uses Boost, you may need an older version of Boost.  Try [1.34.1](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_34_1.html).

Comment: asio was not a boost library when 1.34.1 was released, and I gather from the question that asio is the only reason the OP is introducing boost to the project in the first place...

Comment: ildjarn is correct, I need to have the asio library, which I just found out was introduced in 1.35.  Is there any way to rebuild the boost libraries for MSVC 6.0?  That is what the original app was written in, and the end exe would probably work in NT4 as a one-to-one replacement, right?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using STLport as the standard library implementation instead of the built-in STL that comes with VC6.  I'm using boost 1.32 and STLport 4.6.2 successfully in VC6 with an MFC project.  I haven't tried moving up to newer versions of boost or STLport, but STLport might be enough to get you going.